# Zend 2 "getServiceLocator" was not found

Tags: php, doctrine, zend, zend-framework-2

Toda vez que preciso chamar o Doctrine ORM eu encontro o erro

> A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin
>   manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

Como faço para corrigi-lo ?

Answer (score 0):

De onde você chama o getServiceLocator? (Controller, Service, Module, Event).

Dependendo da sua resposta posso te ajudar mais rápido, se puder manda um trecho do código, outra questão importante qual versão do Zend 1, 2 ou 3?

Grato

Ríder Cantuária

47 9 9168-8318 [whatsapp]